# Solving PDE $xu_x+u_y=x \sinh(y)+u$ using Cauchy Method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the following PDE before me:

$xu_x+u_y=x \sinh(y)+u$
with initial condition $u(0,y)=0$

I wrote the characteristic equations as below:

$x_\tau=x, x(0,s)=0$
$y_\tau=1, y(0,s)=s$
$u_\tau=x \sinh(y)+u, u(0,s)=0$

Solving initial condition problem for $x,y$, I got:

$x=0$

$y=\tau+s$

After putting $x=0$ in equation for $u_\tau$, I got:

$u_\tau=u, u(0,s)=0$

Solving initial condition problem for $u$, I got:

$u=0$.

My question is whether I am doing all this correctly. Is the final answer to this question going to be $u=0$.
Please suggest.

Comment: Obviously the function $u(x,y)=0$ doesn't satisfies the PDE due to the term $x\sinh(y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xu_x+u_y=x \sinh(y)+u$$
Charpit Lagrange characteristic ODEs :

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{x \sinh(y)+u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{1}$ :
$$x\:e^{-y}=c_1$$
$\sinh(y)=\frac12\left(\frac{x}{c_1}-\frac{c_1}{x} \right)$

A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{x \sinh(y)+u}$

$\frac{du}{dx}=\sinh(y)+\frac{u}{x}=\frac12\left(\frac{x}{c_1}-\frac{c_1}{x} \right)+\frac{u}{x}\quad$ which solution is :
$$\frac{u}{x}-\frac{x}{2c_1}-\frac{c_1}{2x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\frac{u}{x}-\frac{x}{2c_1}-\frac{c_1}{2x}=F(x\:e^{-y})$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the boundary condition).
$$\frac{u}{x}-\frac{e^y}{2}-\frac{e^{-y}}{2}=F(x\:e^{-y})$$
The explicit form of the general solution of the PDE is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=x\:\cosh(y)+x\:F(x\:e^{-y})}$$
CONDITION :

$u(0,y)=0=0*\:\cosh(y)+0*F(0\:e^{-y})$

This is true any function $F$. Thus the function $F$ cannot be determined.

Conclusion : They are infinity many solutions which satisfy both the PDE and the specified condition. The equation of those solutions is the above equation of the general solution (any function $F$ ).

Comment: Cudos for the step: $\sinh(y)=0.5(x/c_1 - c_1/x)$

Comment: I think I meant to say kudos... jeez